# ideal operations

Tags: ac.commutative-algebra

Let $R$ be a commutative Noetherian ring, $\mathfrak{a}$ an ideal and $x, y$ elements. Is it true that
$$\mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:x) \cap \mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:y) = \mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:(x,y))?$$

Comment: Acutally, I voted to close this, but I then realized that it was not as trivial as I thought.  Sorry!  I'd retract my vote to close if I could...

Comment: I need this equation for my problem. However, I think it should have a counterexample. 

Comment: It is true that $(\mathfrak{a}:x)\cap(\mathfrak{a}:y)=(\mathfrak{a}:(x,y))$ (see Atiyah-Macdonald p. 8, Ex. 1.12(v)). So the question is, what happens after both sides are multiplied by $\mathfrak{a}$?

Comment: Let $R=\mathbb{C}[a,b,x,y]/\langle abx-aby\rangle$. And let $\mathfrak{a}=\langle ax,by\rangle$.

Now $aby\in \mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:x)\cap \mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:y)$ but $aby\notin \mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:\langle x,y\rangle)$.

This should be your counterexample.

Comment: That's a nice example. Why don't you post that as an answer?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

No it is not true.

Let $R=\mathbb{K}[a,b,x,y]/\langle abx-aby\rangle$ and $\mathfrak{a}=\langle ax,by\rangle$.

Now $abx\in\mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:x)\cap\mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:y)$ but $abx\notin\mathfrak{a}(\mathfrak{a}:\langle x,y\rangle)$.